# Pivoting a non-numeric table in AWS Redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a table in amazon redshift that I want to pivot along one column. E.g.

```
dim1  dim2  val
x     a     4s
x     b     5v
y     a     9l
y     b     3t
```

Would turn into:

```
dim1   a    b  
x      4s   5v
y      9l   3t
```

Note that AWS Redshift does not support pivot, crosstab, unnest, or case extension. Also, the  solution proposed by AWS in https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=126369 is not sufficient because it relies on using aggregation functions, and since my data does not consist of numbers, this wont work reliably (right?).

The best solution I've been able to come up with is a self join:

```
SELECT table.dim1, val as a, b
FROM table
WHERE dim2='a'
JOIN (
  SELECT dim1, val as b 
  FROM table
  WHERE dim2='b') AS t
ON t.dim1 = table.dim1
```

The problem with this solution is that you have to do one self join for each possible value of `dim2`, and this quickly becomes unmanageable since (in my real world case) my table is enormous and there are 20+ different values in `dim2`. For each new value in `dim2` I have to do another self join so:

```
SELECT table.dim1, val as a, b, c
FROM table
WHERE dim2='a'
JOIN (
  SELECT dim1, val as b 
  FROM table
  WHERE dim2='b') AS t
ON t.dim1 = table.dim1
JOIN (
  SELECT dim1, val as c 
  FROM table
  WHERE dim2='c') AS t2
ON t2.dim1 = table.dim1
```

We can see how this can quickly get out of hand. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the AWS answer was sufficient, you can just aggregate over the strings by using max():

```
SELECT dim1, MAX(a) AS a, MAX(b) AS b
FROM (
  SELECT dim1, 
    CASE dim2 WHEN 'a' THEN val ELSE NULL END as a,
    CASE dim2 WHEN 'b' THEN val ELSE NULL END as b
  FROM table
)
GROUP BY dim1;
```

But with an arbitrarily large number of values in `dim2` this is still cumbersome. I'm open to better answers.

Comment: without pivot or cross tab this is the solution I have seen several times

Comment: You can remove the `ELSE NULL` if you want, that is the default option.